# Implementing a singleton bean in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, singleton

I am trying to create a cache class for my website using Spring and have added the following code to my applicationContect.xml file:

```
<bean id="SiteCache" class="Cache.SiteCache">
```

What I am unsure of is how to initialize this class. Do I even need to initialize it myself or does Spring take care of that when the site loads? If so, how would I accept parameters within the constructor?

I would like the class to be used most of the time, as a quicker way of accessing variables to populate the site, but I need a way of checking if there is an instance in the first place, so that I can load an XML file from source otherwise.

What would be the best way to implement a cache in spring?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed all that was necessary was to load the XML file in the constructor of the cache class. I didn't even need to define a bean in the end, simply accepting it in my GET/POST methods for each controller was enough to keep the cache class a singleton. That way the XML file is only loaded once and saved into a cache object when the site gets built. After that the cache object can be used for easier access.

Thanks for the alternative suggestions though, they seem more effective on more complicated systems and it turned out mine didn't really need all that. I also had a rough idea and only needed a bit of reminding!

Answer (score 5):

> What I am unsure of is how to initialize this class.

By default (providing your definition) Spring will create exactly one instance of bean and use it everywhere where other code requires it.

> how would I accept parameters within the constructor?

Check out [*4.4.1.1 Constructor-based dependency injection*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection):

```
<bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo">
  <constructor-arg ref="bar"/>
  <constructor-arg value="42"/>
</bean>
```

and [*4.4.2.7 XML shortcut with the c-namespace*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-c-namespace):

```
<bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo" c:_0-ref="bar" c:_1-ref="baz">
```

> What would be the best way to implement a cache in spring?

Using built-in [Spring cache abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to implement a cache in spring?

In terms of implementing a cache, I would recommend using an existing Cache implementation such as EhCache or similar in conjunction with the Spring [cache abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

This makes caching as simple as annotating a method which should access the cache with `@Cacheable`. Spring will attempt to use the cache before executing the method.

Whilst it might seem simple to write your own cache the hardest part is always the cache invalidation.

Comment: I see, so how exactly could I implement this? Would I keep the bean definition the same and edit every method that needs site information with @Cacheable? Surely it would be easier and less complicated to have one class containing the relevant methods, accessible by the other classes, then if it contains no information, load the XML file?

Comment: Yes you would mark every method that should access the cache as Cacheable. Much as you would mark every method which should be executed in a transaction as Transactional. I would say that implementing your own cache is never easier and less complicated - even if it seems like a simple undertaking at first!

Comment: but if the bean creates an instance of that class on load, what if the constructor loaded the XML file into its own variables etc? Then all the other methods could access that class's methods couldn't it? That way the XML file would only be loaded when the site is first created.

Comment: It sounds like you know what you want to do here. Give it a go! If this XML never expires then it might work.

Comment: I think it worked loading the XML file in the constructor of the cache class, thanks for your help though. I expect with more complicated systems your way would be better, but I just needed a simple singleton class with global accessibility and didn't understand how Spring implemented that.